# Detect mouse click on SELECTION Editable ComboBox JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

The question may seem pretty easy at first, but I've already had troubles with it for a few days.

So, my problem is that I would like to detect mouse click AND the selection when the ComboBox selection is open and the mouse click is made to choose the option.

So, what it should do is detect the MOUSE CLICK on the selection and also get the selected value as well:

[image]

PS: The code for my ComboBox can be seen here:
[Select JavaFX Editable Combobox text on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39830833/select-javafx-editable-combobox-text-on-click)

Feel free to ask additional questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a cell factory, and register a handler with the cell:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ComboBoxMouseClickOnCell extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox<>();
        combo.getItems().addAll("One", "Two", "Three");
        combo.setCellFactory(lv -> {
            ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<String>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    setText(empty ? null : item);
                }
            };
            cell.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
                if (! cell.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("Click on "+cell.getItem());
                }
            });
            return cell ;
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(combo), 300, 180);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the Lambda expressions are not supported at that language level error.

Comment: @EerikMuuli Then either configure your IDE so that you are using Java 8, or convert the lambda expressions to classes.